# Recommended way to make std::unique_ptr of array type without value initialization?

Tags: c++, memory-management, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

I have some C++ code like the following:

```
#include <memory>

void do_memory()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(50);

  int* ptr2 = new int[50];
  delete[] ptr2;
}
```

In the first case case, I'm creating a unique pointer to an int array, and the second case, I'm allocating a raw int array.  Both arrays get cleaned up by the time the scope is left.  Playing around with this code (e.g. https://godbolt.org/g/c3gEfV), I see that the optimized assembly for these two sets of instructions are different because `make_unique` performs value initialization (specifically, it seems to set all the values of the allocated array to 0).  So `make_unique` is introducing a bit of unwanted overhead.

What is the recommended way to allocate a `unique_ptr` to an array (as in the above) *without* automatic value initialization?  I have experimented with e.g.

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[50]);
```

but in my application I also have the restriction that I don't know the size of my array at compile time, so I'd like to not have to allocate any arrays with a (compile-time) constant size.

Comment: What is the problem with `std::unique_ptr<int[]> ptr = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[n]);` ?

Comment: You're introducing added code complexity to avoid value initialization and you've established you need that by looking at the assembly.  Is std::vector too slow in a real-world scenario?  I wonder, are you Prematurely Optimising?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you really must, just write your own function:

```
template <typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> make_unique_uninitialized(const std::size_t size) {
    return unique_ptr<T>(new typename std::remove_extent<T>::type[size]);
}
```

Avoid the temptation to create the `unique_ptr` directly:

```
std::unique_ptr<T[]>(new T[size])  // BAD
```

Because this is not exception-safe in general (for all the usual reasons you use `make_unique` in the first place - consider function calls with multiple arguments and exceptions thrown about).

Comment: Great stuff, thank you! Minor comment on the snippet - `const` could be removed from the `size` parameter.

Answer (score 3):

## C++20 update

C++20 introduces `std::make_unique_for_overwrite`, which works just like `std::make_unique`, except that it does default-initialization instead of value-initialization.